# Similar Table commands differ greatly in run time

Tags: list-manipulation

With version 10.3.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit), the similar codes

```
fx[i_] := 0.0001 i - 2;
t10 = Table[x = fx[i]; FixedPoint[x + (x + (x + (#^2 + x)^2)^2)^2 &, x, 249], 
    {i, 0, 22500}]

t11 = Table[x = 0.0001 i - 2; FixedPoint[x + (x + (x + (#^2 + x)^2)^2)^2 &, x, 249], 
    {i, 0, 22500}];
```

produce the same result and take about 8 seconds each (`AbsoluteTiming`) on my PC.  However,

```
t12 = Table[FixedPoint[x + (x + (x + (#^2 + x)^2)^2)^2 &, x, 249], {x, -2., .25, .0001}];
```

also produces the same result but is over 20 times faster.  Computing `x = 0.0001 i - 2` in itself takes negligible time.  What is the cause of the slowdown?

Comment: What does ``Developer`PackedArrayQ[]`` return for these three?

Comment: @J.M.  Thanks.  Only `t22` is packed, which certainly impacts run time.  However, I would think that most of the time is otherwise consumed by `FixedPoint`, which should not care about packed arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't quite figured out the whole story here, but in any case you are evaluating `x` many times in the `FixedPoint[]` as it iterates a hundred times (on average) for each value. I got much closer to the performance of your third example (0.99 seconds on my machine) by generating the function before running the `Table[]`:

```
Timing[x + (x + (x + (x + #^2)^2)^2)^2 & /. x -> fx[i] // 
    Table[FixedPoint[#, 0.0001 i - 2, 249], {i, 0, 22500}] &;]
```

> ```
> {1.3385, Null}
> ```

But then when I put in `fx[i]` for the initial value in the `FixedPoint[]`, the performance goes to hell again:

```
Timing[x + (x + (x + (x + #^2)^2)^2)^2 & /. x -> fx[i] // 
    Table[FixedPoint[#, fx[i], 249], {i, 0, 22500}] &;]
```

> ```
> {16.4239, Null}
> ```

That's the part I don't get. (See my guess below.)

Using `With`, as noted by bbgodfrey in the comments, the initial value can also be set using `fx[i]` with good performance:

```
Timing[With[{x = fx[i]}, 
    Table[FixedPoint[x + (x + (x + (x + #^2)^2)^2)^2 &, x, 249], {i, 
      0, 22500}]];]
```

> ```
> {1.32898, Null}
> ```

If I try to do the `With` directly on the `FixedPoint[]`, which I might expect to be faster since `i` is known at that point allowing the calculation of `x` to be done just once, then we are nevertheless back to a slow execution:

```
Timing[Table[With[{x = fx[i]}, 
     FixedPoint[x + (x + (x + (x + #^2)^2)^2)^2 &, x, 249]], {i, 0, 
     22500}];]
```

> ```
> {9.14682, Null}
> ```

An important observation is that the result is packed (`PackedArrayQ[]` is true) when it's fast, and false when it's slow. I am guessing that `Table[]` is trying to analyze its arguments to determine if the result will be a machine real, and if so, pre-allocate the result array as a packed array. Putting functions and `With` in the `Table[]` arguments appears to confound that analysis, resulting in `Table[]` having to back off to a result array of arbitrary objects. Though using `N[]` on the first argument of `Table[]` didn't give it the clue, so I'm not sure how to convince it. There may also be some compilation going on here when the analysis shows a machine real computation.

As an aside, the actual fixed points are shown here in blue and orange (there are two possible solutions to converge to for each `i`, except the last one). The solutions reached with the 249 iterations limit are shown in green:

[image: mess]

What a mess. The answers are reliably converging to a fixed point only for *x* >~ –0.75, and for the singular case *x* = –2. The behavior is not numerically stable, so in fact I had to be careful with the order of operations to make sure that I got the same answers.

Comment: Your recommendation seems plausible.  However, copying your code to a notebook, I get a runtime of almost 20 seconds.  What version of Mathematica are you using?

Comment: Sorry — I got fooled for a bit there by your example setting `x` globally. Answer updated.

Comment: Nice work-around.  Thanks.  Another is `Table[With[{x = 0.0001 i - 2}, 
FixedPoint[x + (x + (x + (#^2 + x)^2)^2)^2 &, x, 249]], {i, 0, 22500}];`.  I still would like to know why my first and second examples are so slow.  By the way, the computation is of a strange attractor, so the chaotic behavior is expected.  By the way, did you simply superimpose the orange/blue parabola on the attractor plot?

Comment: Yes, the plot was made with `Show[ListPlot[...],Plot[...]]`.

Comment: I have added the use of `With[]`, and a guess about what's going on.